# How to make the camera rotate while tracking the target

Tags: constraints

I need to make an animation with a camera around the target

At the same time The camera Angle needs to be tilted

But I couldn't rotate the camera when I tried to use “follow path” and “track to” it

[image]

[image]

[image]"

Comment: Add an empty as a child of the main object to 0:0:0 location (so follow the object) and set the camera child of the empty. So when you rotate the empty the camera will move around the object and pointing to it.

Comment: That's a good idea. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Just tried this and you can rotate the camera using 'Damped Track' instead of 'Track To'.

[image: Damped Track Rotate]

Comment: That's what I want. Thank you！

Comment: @YaoFq No problems, glad it helped!

Comment: thanks dan! thanks dan! thanks dan! thanks dan!

Answer (score 0):

`Damped Track` didn't work in my specific case, so I used a second modifier: `Track Rotation` on the empty it's tracking.